# JSONValue cannot be convert to JSONObject

Tags: java, json

I'm fairly new to Java and I'm trying to write an Iterator for my JSON-file.
But it keeps telling me that "incompatible types: JSONValue cannot be convert to JSONObject" at `JSONObject authorNode = (JSONObject) authors.next();`

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.JSONValue;
import mende.entity.Author;


public class JSONIteratorAuthor implements Iterator <Author> {

    private Iterator<JSONValue> authors;

    public JSONIteratorAuthor(JSONObject jsonObject){
        this.authors = ((JSONArray) jsonObject.get("authors")).iterator();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return this.authors.hasNext();
    }

    public Author next() {
        if(this.hasNext()){
            Author a = new Author();
            JSONObject authorNode = (JSONObject) authors.next();
            a.setFirstName((String) authorNode.get("first_name"));
            a.setLastName((String) authorNode.get("last_name"));
            return a;
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
    }    
}
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2):

authors.next(); returns an object of type JSONValue

```
private Iterator<JSONValue> authors;
```

But you are trying to cast it to an incompatible type (JSONObject)

```
JSONObject authorNode = (JSONObject) authors.next();
```

I would guess that your `Iterator<JSONValue>` should instead be `Iterator<JSONObject>` .